# JAVAFX Objects don't free Heap Memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, javafx

I have a simple JavaFX Application that open a Browser and shows google page. After exit the Application and free all objects, I can see that the JavaFX objects like Scene, Stage, WebView  and WebEngine are alive in the heap memory after call GC.
I can see this objects with JProfiler and other Profiler tools.

This is my Test code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestMemoryLeak
{
    private Stage anotherStage;
    private Application app;

    public void initFrame()
    {
        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        ActionListener a1 = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Thread javaFxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new JFXPanel();
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try
                                {
                                    app = MyApplication.class.newInstance();
                                    anotherStage = new Stage();
                                    app.start(anotherStage);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                javaFxThread.setDaemon(true);
                javaFxThread.start();
            }
        };
        btnStart.addActionListener(a1);

        JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");

        ActionListener a2 = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try
                        {
                            anotherStage.close();
                            anotherStage = null;
                            app.stop();
                            Platform.exit();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        btnStop.addActionListener(a2);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStart);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStop);
        frame.setTitle("Memory Leak");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestMemoryLeak().initFrame();
    }
}
```

And my JavaFX Application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 800, 600, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Browser extends Region {
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        // load the web page
        engine.load("http://www.google.es");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

To test the application click on Start Button to show google web page, click on Stop Button to stop the application, run a Profiler tool, and call gc, the JavaFX classes are alive.

I am using java version "1.7.0_51" and windows 8.1

Is there something wrong in my code? Or this is the normal behavior?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I can't understand your question actually. You stop the application the run a Profiler?